# Using two foreach loops

Tags: loops, foreach, stata

I have two `foreach` loops:

1. is tightening instruments[ 1A, 2A, 3A, 4A]
2. is loosening measures [ 1b, 2b, 3b, 4b] (this is not same exact code).

My regression should be running with 1 tightening and 1 loosening measure at the same time. I tried including two loops but that's running one measure at a time. How do I get it to run one variable of each list at the same time (an overall of four regressions)?

```
local MPPTD "MPP_TD CAP_TD LIQ_TD CRE_TD"
local MPPLD "MPP_LD CAP_LD LIQ_LD CRE_LD" 

foreach instrument of local MPPTD { 
    foreach measure of local MPPLD {

    xtreg `dep'`i' drate `instrument' `measure' interaction`instrument' ///
    interaction`measure' `rhsvar', fe
```

Answer (score 2):

Your desired loop is over four cases, so one loop not two nested loops. In general, you might do something like

```
 local Alist frog toad newt dragon  
 local Blist Harry Hermione Ron Neville 

 forval j = 1/4 { 
      * code in terms of word `j' of `Alist' and word `j' of `Blist' 
 }
```

and there are other ways to do it.

In your case there is simple structure that exists to be exploited:

```
local prefix MPP CAP LI  CRE 

foreach pre of local prefix { 
    * code in terms of `pre'LD and `pre'TD 
}
```

and I can see no objection to

```
foreach pre in MPP CAP LI CRE {
```

Answer (score 1):

Nick's answer is spot on as usual. [Extended macro functions](https://www.stata.com/manuals13/pmacrolists.pdf) are key. For something even more general, I like an implementation like the following:

```
local MPPTD "MPP_TD CAP_TD LIQ_TD CRE_TD"
local MPPLD "MPP_LD CAP_LD LIQ_LD CRE_LD"
assert `:list sizeof MPPTD' == `:list sizeof MPPLD'
    // The above line ensures the 2 locals have the same num of elements

forvalues i = 1/`:list sizeof MPPTD' { 
    local instrument: word `i' of `MPPTD'
    local measure: word `i' of `MPPLD'
    xtreg `dep'`i' drate `instrument' `measure' interaction`instrument' ///
    interaction`measure' `rhsvar', fe
}
```